# trouble during reinstall hololens unseccessful

Tags: hololens, reinstall

i get into a trouble. A few days ago i bought a hololens 2. It was necessary to reinstal that but during reinstallation  there were a error and reinstallation wasnt successfully done. Now i wasnt to run the glasese it isnt able to detect device in pc. during a charging still light just first led. I try lots of way to solve that but without success. please could you give me any advice ?

tnak you

jarda

i used advance recovery companion automatic and manual detecting. No feedback from this SW. If i try to reset hololens in a device manager there isnt a hololens recovery device

Answer (score 0):

For this one, best advice is to open a direct support ticket with Microsoft for hardware support:
aka.ms/HLSupport

The Microsoft support team can validate the hardware and assist further.

Thanks,

Nathan